# Getting a 401 when trying to logout with Loopback API

Tags: node.js, vue.js, loopbackjs, axios

I've got a Loopback js api and a Vue js app that I'm trying to get to talk to each other, but I'm getting a weird error. I'm trying to POST logout from my Vue app, but it keeps giving me a 401 even though it works fine when I do it from the Loopback api explorer.

My request is to `http://localhost:3000/api/employees/logout` with payload `access_token : "XXX"` where employees is my model extending User.

The code making the client-side request is

```
  axios.post(`${store.api.url}/employees/logout`, {
    access_token: store.state.authentication.auth.id
  })
  .then(() => {
    store.commit('resetAuth');
    this.$router.push({ name: 'login' });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And yes, I am authenticated and the token does exist on the other end.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it was permissions -_-

If you don't have permission to access an object, even if you are authenticated, it returns a 401, not a 403 like I was expecting.

Comment: can you please elaborate ... what about permissions ?

Comment: I don't know much about loopback, but there's an acl type permission system that grants access to your objects.  If you don't have permission to access an object, you get a 401 response (not authenticated) instead of a 403 (forbidden).  Could have had to do with me messing around with a logout route as well.

Answer (score 0):

did you add authentication.js script to server/boot and re check ACL for employee model ? Those are the loose ends in certain problems, I guess.

Comment: Yes, when I figured out it was a permission error and not an authentication error, I just had to figure out how to add myself as an admin.